# python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having a difficult time understanding how to get python to call a system command with the `subprocess.Popen` function.

```
the_file = ('logs/consolidated.log.gz')         
webstuff = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zgrep', '/meatsauce/', the_file ],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  for line in webstuff.stdout:
    print line
```

Trying to get python to build another file with my search string.

Comment: I have no clue how you intend what you wrote to work...

Comment: [Don't use `Popen.stdout` - use `Popen.communicate()`.](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Comment: possible duplicate of [python system call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436740/python-system-call)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you're constructing your arguments. The way you have it now, you're running:

`/usr/bin/zgrep /meatsauce/ logs/consolidated.log.gz`

Note the space between `/meatsauce/` and `logs`...

To do what I think you're intending, use `os.path.join` a la:

```
import os

the_file = 'logs/consolidated.log.gz'         
webstuff = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zgrep', os.path.join('/meatsauce/', the_file)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) % dpt_search
    for line in webstuff.stdout:
        print line
```

Comment: I don't think the `% dpt_search` at the end is correct either.

Comment: yes, thank you, i now understand...  and also my mistake for not cleaning the %s stuff.

Comment: so... now that i have the output in webstuff.stdout... how would i stick that into a new file, then compress it with gzip?

Comment: answer:     the_file = ('webalizerlogs/consolidated.log.gz')
    output_f = open('output.txt','w')
    webstuff = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zgrep', dpt_search, the_file ],stdout=output_f)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure about your question, but the following snippet will call `zgrep` with two arguments, a searchterm and a filename - and print the result (`stdout`) line by line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess

# filename and searchterm
fn, term = 'access_log.gz', 'hello'
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zgrep', term, fn], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
    print line
```

In the code you posted the string interpolation (`% dpt_search`) does not work out, since there is not pure string in front of the modulo sign - in fact it should fail with something like:

`TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Popen' and 'str'"`

Answer (score 1):

```
the_file = ('webalizerlogs/consolidated.log.gz')
output_f = open('output.txt','w')
webstuff = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zgrep', dpt_search, the_file ],stdout=output_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply trying to grep the a content in the a file. Is it?

```
import os
import subprocess
the_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'logs/consolidated.log.gz')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zgrep', dpt_search, the_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
with open('resultoutput','w') as f:
     f.write(out)
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/zip',os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'resultoutput'])
```

Check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) as well.

Comment: yes, but this prints my results... i would like python to create a new file for me, and gzip it

Comment: open a file, write the result as the then gzip it. Doing this in python is straight forward. Updated the answer.