# python system call

Tags: python

having a difficult time understanding how to get python to call a system function...

```
the_file = ('logs/consolidated.log.gz')         
webstuff = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/zgrep', '/meatsauce/', the_file ],stdout=subprocess.PIPE) % dpt_search
    for line in webstuff.stdout:
        print line
```

Trying to get python to build another file with my search string.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue how you intend what you wrote to work...

Comment: :)  in perl, you would write system or qx ("/usr/bin/zgrep blah filename > output");

Comment: You have a `%` in there. That is not where `%` *could* go, much less where it *would* go.

Comment: Running a subprocess and parsing its output != system call

Comment: possible duplicate of [python subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432134/python-subprocess-popen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [PyMotW Subprocess page](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/) from Doug Hellmann who (quoted) "Reads the docs so you don't have to"

Apart from that:

```
f = file('sourcefile')
for line in f:
    if 'pattern' in line:
            # mind the , at the end,
            # since there's no stripping involved
            # and print adds a newline without it
            print line,
```

if you need to match regular expressions apart from the documentation in the [Python Standard Library documentation for the re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) also refer to the [PyMotW Regular Expression page](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/re/index.html)